# How to get iOS crash logs when syncing to the cloud

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash

If a user only syncs with iCloud, how can I get their crash logs?  I've had them try to sync with their computer, but it doesn't appear to copy them to their computer.

Answer (score -1):

connect their device to your development machine with Xcode. You will find their Crash Log available in Window > Organizer > Devices > (the device's name) > Device Logs.

[image: Device Logs]

p.s. you may need to wait for half a minute for Xcode to start copying over the Crash Logs.

Comment: This is a tester who's device I don't have access to.  I'm trying to explain to them how to retrieve the crash logs so they can send them to me.

Comment: then tell them connect their device to their own Mac and get the crash logs with Xcode.

Comment: As stated, after telling the user to do this, they were unable to find the files on their computer.  Hence the question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that you can Drag-n-Drop the list item (that's the highlighted "Fruit   Crash   21/12/12 11:4...") to Finder to copy the crash log file.

Comment: In windows popup it is showing "Could not find Developer Disk Image". Could you please suggest?

Comment: @WannaCoffee "Could not find Developer Disk Image" means the iOS version installed on the device was not supported by your Xcode. Please install appropriate Xcode version. e.g. iOS 9.3 -> Xcode 7.3, iOS 10 -> Xcode 8, iOS 10.1 -> Xcode 8.1.